# Unable to determine activity name

Tags: java, android

I'm currently having a problem with an Error running 'app'.
It said that it's unable to determine activity name.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bottomnavigationview, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){ // MainActivity로 화면전환
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }

        if(id==R.id.backward){ //추후 뒤로가기 액티비티로 추가
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if(id ==R.id.chat_bot){
            Intent settingIntent = new Intent(this, ChatBot.class);

            startActivity(settingIntent);
            
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

This is my MainActivity.Java, and I made menu xml to change activity by clicking the menu.
There is two Activity, MainActivity and ChatBot.

Hope I can handle this problem in here. Thanks.

I heard that it has some dependency problem, so I tried to fix the gradle(app) file to add some modules. But there is only Kotline code for it. Since I am using java, I wanna know how to add modules in java language.

++
here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Team2App_ToolBar"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatBot"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false" />



</application>
```

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file? Also, can you share the entire error log? And is your ChatBot class an activity?